# Full-Text Search Function not working at all

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I’m a self-taught PHP enthusiast.
I got the following code to perform a search. 
The function stringToSearch cleans all the “portuguese” dangerous characters, the function jm_search performs the search… and everything goes fine, the search is done without any problem.

Now I want to perform Full-text Search and I’ve adapted the first code to do it but somehow it isn’t working…always returns 0 results.
I’ve been working around but no success so far.

First piece of code

```
function stringToSearch($str) { 
//Let’s transform string to lowercase
$str = trim(strtolower($str));

//Taking out extra spaces from string... “long  word” or “long       word” becomes “long word”
while ( strpos($str,"  ") )
$str = str_replace("  "," ",$str);

//Change de dangerous characters "ã,á..." by clean characters "a"

$caracteresDanger = array ("Ã","ã","Õ","õ","á","Á","é","É","í","Í","ó","Ó","ú","Ú","ç","Ç","à","À","è","È","ì","Ì","ò","Ò","ù","Ù","ä","Ä","ë","Ë","ï","Ï","ö","Ö","ü","Ü","Â","Ê","Î","Ô","Û","â","ê","î","ô","û","!","?");
$caracteresClean = array ("a","a","o","o","a","a","e","e","i","i","o","o","u","u","c","c","a","a","e","e","i","i","o","o","u","u","a","a","e","e","i","i","o","o","u","u","A","E","I","O","U","a","e","i","o","u",".",".",".",".",".",".","." ,"." ,".");
$str = str_replace($caracteresDanger,$caracteresClean,$str);
//Now we don’t have any danger character in the string, and all are "lower",


//Let’s build the Regular Expression to MySQL
$caractresSimple = array("a","e","i","o","u","c");
$caractresEnvelope = array("[a]","[e]","[i]","[o]","[u]","[c]");

$str = str_replace($caractresSimple,$caractresEnvelope,$str);
$caracteresForRegExp = array("(a|ã|á|à|ä|â|&atilde;|&aacute;|&agrave;|&auml;|&acirc;|Ã|Á|À|Ä|Â|&Atilde;|&Aacute;|&Agrave;|&Auml;|&Acirc;)",
"(e|é|è|ë|ê|&eacute;|&egrave;|&euml;|&ecirc;|É|È|Ë|Ê|&Eacute;|&Egrave;|&Euml;|&Ecirc;)",
"(i|í|ì|ï|î|&iacute;|&igrave;|&iuml;|&icirc;|Í|Ì|Ï|Î|&Iacute;|&Igrave;|&Iuml;|&Icirc;)", 
"(o|õ|ó|ò|ö|ô|&otilde;|&oacute;|&ograve;|&ouml;|&ocirc;|Õ|Ó|Ò|Ö|Ô|&Otilde;|&Oacute;|&Ograve;|&Ouml;|&Ocirc;)",
"(u|ú|ù|ü|û|&uacute;|&ugrave;|&uuml;|&ucirc;|Ú|Ù|Ü|Û|&Uacute;|&Ugrave;|&Uuml;|&Ucirc;)",
"(c|ç|Ç|&ccedil;|&Ccedil;)" );
$str = str_replace($caractresEnvelope,$caracteresForRegExp,$str);

//Changing spaces by .*
$str = str_replace(" ",".*",$str);

//Return final String!
return $str;
}

function jm_search(){
global $database, $sstring, $scategory, $my, $cinConfig, $Itemid, $option, $mainframe;
$scategory = 'description';
$str=stringToSearch($sstring);
$searchTerms = $scategory.” REGEXP \"" . $str . "\"";
$query = "SELECT * FROM #__jmovies WHERE ".$searchTerms." AND published = 1 AND access <= ".(int)$my->gid." ORDER BY title”;

$database->setQuery($query);
//echo $database->getQuery();
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
$total = count($rows);
}
```

Second piece of code (Full-text Search)

```
function jm_search(){
global $database, $sstring, $scategory, $my, $cinConfig, $Itemid, $option, $mainframe;
$scategory = 'description'     
$str=stringToSearch($sstring);
$searchArray = explode(" ", $str);
$query="SELECT * FROM #__jmovies WHERE  MATCH (`description`) AGAINST ('";
$i=0;
foreach ($searchArray as $word) {
$query .= "+".$word."* ";
}

$query .= "' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND published = 1 AND access <= ".(int)$my->gid." ORDER BY title";
$database->setQuery($query);
//echo $database->getQuery();
$rows = $database->loadObjectList();
$total = count($rows);        
}
```

Comment: If you don't do it in boolean mode, do you get any results?

Comment: I'm suspicious of building a query with a loop like this.  Spit out the actual query before you execute it to see if anything looks off.

Comment: Removing accents is unnecessary. If your MySQL encoding is set properly, FULLTEXT index will handle this on its own without any headache. Removing accents is always a bad idea, especially using a list like this.
I suspect encoding issue (ie, your DB contains garbage). Please post query and table contents as displayed by phpmyadmin (not by your code).

Comment: none of the suggestions above worked...:(